# failed to run any pipenv command on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I'm currently a newbie for creating a virtual environment for my project. I have and only have python 3.8 installed on my computer, I also checked my environment variable all working well. So I just installed pipenv through pip by doing `pip install pipenv` and I've tried to call it on my command prompt by `pipenv` which is fine at this point. but I can't seem to call `pipenv shell` or anything else because it threw me some errors like this

```
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 328, in find_all_python_versions
path_list = sorted(versions, key=version_sort, reverse=True) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'version_sort'
```

running other pip commands (e.g virtualenv) runs perfectly fine for me. my pip version is also the lastest and already satisfied.

my current directory for python is under :

> C:\Python

I already look through another source for this particular problem like [this](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4296). and I can't seems to work it out because they mostly use a Unix based solution. I need this for my windows 10. I'm looking forward for your answer. thank you very much

Comment: I already mention that inside my question hyperlink (last paragraph) @phd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First uninstall the current version of pipenv by writing

```
pip uninstall pipenv
```

then reinstall using

```
pip install pipenv==2018.11.26
```

then use command

```
pipenv shell
```

This will solve your problem...

Comment: I think it will be very helpful on providing the source of the solution so that others can have more context on the said problem - see from 
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4296

Answer (score 0):

First step:

```sh
pip uninstall pipenv
```

Now install this version:

```sh
pip install pipenv==**2018.11.26**
```

Now you can create your virtual environment using command-:

```sh
pipenv shell
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider formatting your code with the code editor on future questions/answers. This will help people to more easily read your reply. Thanks for taking the effort to answer!